# Adding Gridview into columns makes the page empty. Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to add a gridview that has 2 columns and 3 rows. My problem is that when I try to add it to my Row it makes the whole page disappear. Here is my code

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        elevation: 0.5,
        title: Text("Home", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.black45)),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
              child: Text("Shop Category", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black, fontFamily: 'Raleway'),textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
            ),
            new GridView.count(
              primary: true,
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Image.asset('assets/images/meat.jpg')
              ],
            )
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just add the `shrinkWrap` property to your `GridView`

```
new GridView.count(
        shrinkWrap: true,
```

Comment: because you are using a SingleChildScrollView + Column , it doesn't know how much it will have to expand, so just set shrink true and it works !

Answer (score 4):

`Column` and `GridView` both take the full screen as it is the default behavior of both widgets, so we have to shrink `GridView` to the minimum size, that should be occupied in the screen.

```
GridView.count(
              primary: true,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Image.asset('assets/images/meat.jpg')
              ],
            )
```

---

`shrinkWrap:true` - With this GridView only occupies the space it needs.

`physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` - It disables the scrolling functionality of GridView, which means now we have only `SingleChildScrollView` who provides the scrolling functionality.